# Can I use several FULLTEXT() searches in a query?

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangojs

How can I change the query so that I can use two fulltext searches in one query? Under here is a simplified version of my query now. It does not work - it only gives me results from the first `FULLTEXT()` search.

```
    FOR doc IN FULLTEXT(@@collection, "this.is.my.path", "prefix:headph") OR  FULLTEXT(@@collection, "antoher.path", "random words")   
RETURN doc
```

Answer (score 1):

[FULLTEXT()](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-fulltext.html#fulltext) returns an array, which is always true and thus the right-hand side of `OR` is fully ignored.

What you could do is `APPEND(FULLTEXT(…), FULLTEXT(…))` to iterate over both of their result sets. You may also use `UNION_DISTINCT()` since `FULLTEXT()` doesn't return results in a particular order anyway.

For a more sophisticated fulltext search engine with ranking see [ArangoSearch](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/arangosearch.html).